# Php using Foreach and obtain a single result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've a table in mysql where I find some values and put them in an array.

Assume that the value of the array are 1 and 5

Now I use this array for a query in another table where I have 5 id and I'd like that it shows me all the id minus the ones of the array (so only 2,3,4)

This is the code I use to pass the foreach in a query

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $arr=array();   

    $query= "SELECT * FROM test WHERE data NOT LIKE '%$value%'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["id"];
    }
}
```

The result I'd like to obtain is "2,3,4" but it gives to me 2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4

This is the array creation

```
$array= array();
$query= "SELECT * FROM test WHERE time1>= '$startTime' AND time1 <=    '$endTime'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$array[]=$row["data"];
}
```

How can do?

Comment: You have NOT LIKE  in your query, is it what you really want?

Comment: Your question is not really clear with respect to the structure of your table. Of what type are the columns `id` and `data`? It is also doubtful whether you really want to execute the SQL query for each value of your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do a better SQL query?

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM test WHERE data NOT IN (".implode(',',$array).")";
```

Or translating:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE data NOT IN (1,5)
```

Comment: Hi I tried but it doesn't work...perhaps it's not good my code to create the array?I posted it in my question right now thanks

Comment: It seems that `data` isn't a INT type. I think you don't know what you want to do here. Give real examples and real expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `$query= "SELECT * FROM test WHERE data NOT LIKE '%$value%' AND id NOT IN ({implode(',',$array_of_ids_you_dont_want)})";` ?

Edit:

I have added an 'id' key to your first array  and moved the 'data' field to 'data' key.

```
$array= array();
$query= "SELECT * FROM test WHERE time1>= '$startTime' AND time1 <=    '$endTime'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[]= array(
        'id'=>$row['id'],
        'data'=>$row["data"]
    );
}
```

Having the id available you can than use array_map function to get a new array of all ids. You can then use this array to construct the where condition. It is wise you use that before the foreach because it will be same for each iteration. Finally now that $array contains sub arrays, when foreaching the element will be the array with id and data keys from above.

```
$exclude_ids = array_map(function($el){return $el['id'];},$array);
$exclude_ids_query = "id NOT IN ({implode(',',$exclude_ids)})";

foreach ($array as $element) {
    $arr=array();   
    $query= "SELECT * FROM test WHERE data NOT LIKE '%{$element['data']}%'".$exclude_ids_query;
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried but it doesn't work...perhaps it's not good my code to create the array?I posted it in my question right now thanks

Comment: it gives Warning: array_map() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: Yes you are correct, I forgot to pass $array as second parameter for the array_map. I have edited my answer.